# How to split a large JSON API responses into smaller requests?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, rest

I am developing an api for getting users details from a MySQL database. I use PHP 7 and Angular 9. I am planning to develop an api endpoint for getting user's list. But I am bit confused about the performance, because my users list has over 3 millions of users, and whether it may slowdown my application.

Are there any way/method for getting that amount of large data via api as JSON object without slowing down?

Or, can we split JSON response, such as 1000 records per time?

Comment: Pagination will do the work.

Comment: `LIMIT <offset>, <hits>` is how you decide what MySQL should return - the offset is the row it should start at; `0` starts at the beginning, `1000` starts 1000 rows into the query results, etc. `hits` decide how many rows to return; `LIMIT 0, 1000` returns the first 1000 rows of your result set, `LIMIT 1000, 1000` returns the next 1000, etc.